# Trying to join windows insider program windows 10 error 0x0

Tags: windows-insider

I keep getting error code 0x0 when pressing the button for windows insider program located in the settings

Comment: Are you using a Microsoft account on this computer?

Comment: @John: yes that is correct

Comment: Please let us know if this Microsoft article helps you  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/windows-insider-error-0x0/88089e70-a29d-4d0c-8f23-50d66791f3c5

Comment: @John: I don't have the registry key in regedit. The cleanmgr did not work.

Comment: Try this Microsoft link to get the Insider download ISO:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced   Also, be sure you have signed up as an Insider so that you can sign in to get this ISO

Comment: @John: Yes that worked